# losetup -d giving : device busy

Tags: lvm, kvm-virtualization, kpartx

I am mounting a KVM disk (LVM) following these commands :

```
# losetup /dev/loop0 foo.img
# kpartx -av /dev/loop0
# mount /dev/mapper/loop0p1 /mnt

# unmount /mnt
# kpartx -dv /dev/loop0
# losetup -d /dev/loop0
```

Problem is when I want to do kpartx -d /dev/loop0 I get :

```
    device-mapper: remove ioctl failed: Device or resource busy
    device-mapper: remove ioctl failed: Device or resource busy
```

I tried looking for it with lsof, but I can't find anything, anyone any idea how I can force  this or what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See if it's used by device-mapper still (`dmsetup table`) and if so, flush the appropriate map (`dmsetup clear mapname`).

Comment: Oh thank Christ! This has been driving me insane...